# Ruby: Defining attributes by looping an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define attributes from an array like so:

```
["a", "b", "c"].each do |field|
  @recipe.field = "anything"
end
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
@store.a = "anything"
@store.b = "anything"
@store.c = "anything"
```

Do you know what I should do with the @store.*field* above? I tried @store.send(field), but that is not working for me and I have no idea what keywords to search to find a solution to the above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setter method for attribute `a` is known as `a=`, so you can use `send` with an argument `"a="` to call the setter method:

```
["a", "b", "c"].each do |field|
  @recipe.send(field + "=", "anything")
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Brian =) I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically add attributes to class, then you should use `attr_accessor` mthod (or check what it does

```
class Recipe
  attr_accessor *["a", "b", "c"]
end

["a", "b", "c"].each do |field|
  @recipe.send("#{field}=", "anything")
end
```

*Edit:*
As you see in example, if you want to assign something to field defined by `def attr=` method, then you need to call `send` with `"attr=", value` params.

Comment: Thank you MBO! You and Brian are awesome. Thank you!